# Is there any way to match file with number in its name in apache Ant build.xml

Tags: java, ant, devops, build-tools

I am trying to match file which has number in its name. And looks like Ant supports only * ? c these characters for regex. Anyone tried ANT regex.
I want to match the file with name TEST-3000-6564345.zip

```
<target name="demo">
    <mkdir dir="/dem"/>
    <unzip dest="src/main/resources/dem">
        <fileset dir="src/main/resources">
            <filename regex=".*[0-9]\d.*"/>
        </fileset>
    </unzip>
</target>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions, but they’re not supported by ordinary patternsets.  Instead, you need to use a selector, like [<filename>](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/selectors.html#filenameselect):

```xml
<fileset dir="${files.root}">
    <filename regex=".*\d.*"/>
</fileset>
```

Comment: java.util.zip.ZipException: archive is not a ZIP archive

Comment: First, `\d` *is* a digit, so `[0-9]\d` is trying to match two consecutive digits.  Second, if you’re trying to match zip files, you probably should use `regex=".*\d.*\.zip"`. The error is telling you that your fileset is matching files which are not zip files.